# Case distinction in B-tree deletion

Tags: data-structures, search-trees

Here is how deletion in B-trees is described:

> 1. If the key k is in node x and x is a leaf, delete the key k from x.
> 2. If the key k is in node x and x is an internal node, do the following.
>
>    a) If the child y that precedes k in node x has at least t keys, then find the predecessor k0 of k in the sub-tree rooted at y. Recursively delete k0, and replace k by k0 in x. (We can find k0 and delete it in a single downward pass.)
>
>    b) If y has fewer than t keys, then, symmetrically, examine the child z that follows k in node x. If z has at least t keys, then find the successor k0 of k in the subtree rooted at z. Recursively delete k0, and replace k by k0 in x. (We can find k0 and delete it in a single downward pass.)
>
>    c) Otherwise, if both y and z have only t-1 keys, merge k and all of z into y, so that x loses both k and the pointer to z, and y now contains 2t-1 keys. Then free z and recursively delete k from y.
> 3. If the key k is not present in internal node x, determine the root x.c(i) of the appropriate subtree that must contain k, if k is in the tree at all. If x.c(i) has only t-1 keys, execute step 3a or 3b as necessary to guarantee that we descend to a node containing at least t keys. Then finish by recursing on the appropriate child of x.

What is the actual difference between case 1 case 3? Both seem to be directing to a leaf node.

Comment: From the description, I think this is about B-trees, not binary (search) trees.

Comment: Incidentally, you can probably tell that there's a good reason why undergraduate textbooks never give a B-tree delete algorithm. If you're actually trying to implement B-trees, there's an alternative which is much simpler to understand. Ask Google about relaxed balance B-trees.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, "case 1" dictates what happens when we reach the appropriate leaf node.

"case 3" tells us what we do when we're still higher up in the tree.

---

Small example: suppose we have {x, y, z} in a tree like so:

```
  y
 / \
x   z
```

and we delete x. We start out at y and hit case 3, determining that "x" must be in the left subtree.

```
  y <-- we are here, and hit case 3
 / \
x   z
```

Thus, we recurse on the left subtree. We then reach x, and execute case 1.

```
                                  y
                                 / \
we are here, and hit case 1 --> x   z
```